# How can I remove Vista folder tabs?

Tags: windows-vista, tabs, sorting

How can I remove the sorting tabs COMPLETELY in folders in Vista Home Premium SP2 OS?
You can see the details in the below image:

[image: vista screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can remove all but NAME, just right click on the bar and remove the checkmarks of the columns you may not want to be displayed.

Comment: Yes,I can choose to disable other tabs but the NAME but I want to disable all tabs completely.It's really fool in Vista.

Comment: no can do, in DETAIL view you MUST have at least the name column enabled, or DETAIL view would be useless as you'll only get empty windows. if you don't like this bar, change the view from DETAIL to LIST, voilá, no more bar.

Comment: I already selected the option "list" as a view style.But it's still showing me those annoying tabs.

Comment: I think he want to remove the headers, not some columns

Comment: yes,I want to completely remove that headers...

Comment: It's showing you the header under the "List" view? I'm using list and I don't have that header...

Answer (score 1):

They can only be hidden if that functionality was made accessible, say through explorer options.

The closest I came to an answer, is using [API calls](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/listview.aspx) to tell the list view to hide the columns, for example a 3rd party tool could do this. I don't know of any 3rd party tools that implement this already.

Unless we can find or make such a tool, we're stuck with the columns.

Comment: so what do I have to do?

Comment: You're looking for a one-line answer, but there isn't one. You live with explorer as is, or disown it and use something like NexusFile (http://xiles.net)

Comment: yep I also know Win 7 and Win Xp both are less pathetic than Vista.So I would like to get rid of this silly bar...